# Como poner un bucle en esta función

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

ya tengo la función de clonar los elementos que estén dentro de "li", ahora yo quiero saber si es posible, **ponerle un límite?** , me explico quiero que se repita 100 veces, lo e intentado con **do while,** y con un **for** pero no me da el codigo se me daña y no aparece nada, me pueden ayudar? , en el fiddle esta el codigo actualizado con el **FOR**!.

```js
/**
 * Endless Scroll plugin for jQuery
 *
 * v1.4.8
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Fred Wu
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * // using default options
 * $(document).endlessScroll();
 *
 * // using some custom options
 * $(document).endlessScroll({
 *   fireOnce: false,
 *   fireDelay: false,
 *   loader: "<div class=\"loading\"><div>",
 *   callback: function(){
 *     alert("test");
 *   }
 * });
 *
 * Configuration options:
 *
 * bottomPixels  integer          the number of pixels from the bottom of the page that triggers the event
 * fireOnce      boolean          only fire once until the execution of the current event is completed
 * fireDelay     integer          delay the subsequent firing, in milliseconds, 0 or false to disable delay
 * loader        string           the HTML to be displayed during loading
 * data          string|function  plain HTML data, can be either a string or a function that returns a string,
 *                                when passed as a function it accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number
 *                                of times the event triggered during the current page session)
 * insertAfter   string           jQuery selector syntax: where to put the loader as well as the plain HTML data
 * callback      function         callback function, accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number of times
 *                                the event triggered during the current page session)
 * resetCounter  function         resets the fire sequence counter if the function returns true, this function
 *                                could also perform hook actions since it is applied at the start of the event
 * ceaseFire     function         stops the event (no more endless scrolling) if the function returns true
 *
 * Usage tips:
 *
 * The plugin is more useful when used with the callback function, which can then make AJAX calls to retrieve content.
 * The fire sequence argument (for the callback function) is useful for 'pagination'-like features.
 */

(function($){

  $.fn.endlessScroll = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      bottomPixels: 50,
      fireOnce: true,
      fireDelay: 150,
      loader: "<br />Loading...<br />",
      data: "",
      insertAfter: "div:last",
      resetCounter: function() { return false; },
      callback: function() { return true; },
      ceaseFire: function() { return false; }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var firing       = true;
    var fired        = false;
    var fireSequence = 0;

    if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
      firing = false;
    }

    if (firing === true) {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
          firing = false;
          return; // Scroll will still get called, but nothing will happen
        }

        if (this == document || this == window) {
          var is_scrollable = $(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels;
        } else {
          // calculates the actual height of the scrolling container
          var inner_wrap = $(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap", this);
          if (inner_wrap.length == 0) {
            inner_wrap = $(this).wrapInner("<div class=\"endless_scroll_inner_wrap\" />").find(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap");
          }
          var is_scrollable = inner_wrap.length > 0 &&
            (inner_wrap.height() - $(this).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels);
        }

        if (is_scrollable && (options.fireOnce == false || (options.fireOnce == true && fired != true))) {
          if (options.resetCounter.apply(this) === true) fireSequence = 0;

          fired = true;
          fireSequence++;

          $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_loader\">" + options.loader + "</div>");

          data = typeof options.data == 'function' ? options.data.apply(this, [fireSequence]) : options.data;

          if (data !== false) {
            $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_data\">" + data + "</div>");
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").hide().fadeIn();
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").removeAttr("id");

            options.callback.apply(this, [fireSequence]);

            if (options.fireDelay !== false || options.fireDelay !== 0) {
              $("body").after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_marker\"></div>");
              // slight delay for preventing event firing twice
              $("div#endless_scroll_marker").fadeTo(options.fireDelay, 1, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                fired = false;
              });
            }
            else {
              fired = false;
            }
          }

          $("div#endless_scroll_loader").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
  /*  calculo la cantidad de imagenes que tenes "cargadas"*/
    var cantidad_imagenes = $('#images li').size();

    $(document).endlessScroll({
      inflowPixels: 300,
      callback: function() {


        for ($x = 0; $cantidad_imagenes <= 100; $x++) {
          
                  /*en base a esa cantidad elijo una posición de alguna de ellas al azar y la guardo en la variable random.*/
                  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));

                  /*Por ultimo clono la imagen en la posicion que acabo de calcular y la agregamos al final.*/
                  var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();

                  $('#images').append(img);
          }



  
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 640px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Infinite Scrolling through Images</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <h1>Infinite Scrolling, Demo 3</h1>

  <ul id="images">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Podrias aclarar dentro de todo el codigo que subiste donde se te "daña" al poner un for (o un while) tambien podrias mostrar esa parte solamente con el for incluido, no vaya a ser que solo sea porque lo escribiste incorrectamente.

Comment: hola listo ya lo agrego, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en el ciclo for, deberias usar la variable $x en la condicion y no la variable cantidad_imagenes ya que puede entrar en un bucle infinito o ni siquiera entrar directamente. de hecho, podrias usar la cantidad_imagenes como limite. Depende tu caso.

```
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {

              /*en base a esa cantidad elijo una posición de alguna de ellas al azar y la guardo en la variable random.*/
              var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));

              /*Por ultimo clono la imagen en la posicion que acabo de calcular y la agregamos al final.*/
              var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();

              $('#images').append(img);
      }
```

o sino

```
    for ($x = 0; $x <= cantidad_imagenes; $x++) {

              /*en base a esa cantidad elijo una posición de alguna de ellas al azar y la guardo en la variable random.*/
              var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));

              /*Por ultimo clono la imagen en la posicion que acabo de calcular y la agregamos al final.*/
              var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();

              $('#images').append(img);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy probablemente tu error venga porque estas tratando las variables en el callback como si fueran PHP en vez javascript ademas de que estas creando un bucle infinito. Puesto que en el momento del `for`, si `cantidad_imagenes` es menor que 100, siempre va a ser menor que 100.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*  calculo la cantidad de imagenes que tenes "cargadas"*/
    var cantidad_imagenes = $('#images li').size();

    $(document).endlessScroll({
      inflowPixels: 300,
      callback: function() {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {

                  /*en base a esa cantidad elijo una posición de alguna de ellas al azar y la guardo en la variable random.*/
                  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));

                  /*Por ultimo clono la imagen en la posicion que acabo de calcular y la agregamos al final.*/
                  var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();

                  $('#images').append(img);
          }

      }
    });
});
```